# design printing theme for kaddressbook (grantlee)

Tags: kde, kaddressbook, kontact

I would like to create a printing theme for kaddressbook that allows me to print my contacts on label stickers 70x32mm. The problem is, I don't know enough html/css/grantlee to make it work. Any guru around who can just do this in a couple of minutes?